# How to we access SwitftyDropbox api for Objective-C

Tags: dropbox-api

I have a mixed Objective-C and Swift project. The UI is mostly Swift and the MODEL part of the code is Objective-C.

I have been able to access the SwiftyDropbox api from the my Swift code.

How can I access the new Dropbox API from my Objective-C ?
Do I have to create my own wrapper for the Dropbox swift functions ?
The SwiftyDropbox api does not seem to be available when I:

## import "MyPackage-Swift.h"

Comment: Please refer to this thread: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/204715229-To-use-API-v2-in-iOS-platform-we-need-an-objective-C-version

Comment: I hope they solve the interop problem soon. When I first read the blog a while back they indicated that we would be able to call the Swift API from

Comment: The official Objective-C SDK for Dropbox API v2 has been released here: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-obj-c